# Javascript: ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

This is very basic. I try to instantiate a Class defined in an external .js file embedded. The code of the .js is simply this.

```
(function() {
  var MyClass;

  MyClass = (function() {

    function MyClass() {}

    MyClass.prototype.name = function(name) {};

    return MyClass;

  })();

}).call(this);
```

And the HTML is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Sample Page</title>
    <script src="file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

If I try on the console to instantiate the class but I see a `ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined`:

```
var myVar
myVar = new MyClass
> ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined
```

If I try to call `MyClass` directly from console I get the same error

```
> ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined
```

I'm sure I missing something terrible obvious here but yet I can figure it out what.

**Updated**: To create the javascript coded I'm using CoffeScript, the code is simply this.

```
class MyClass
  acc: (name) ->
```

The proposed answers codes when converted back to CoffeScript using http://js2coffee.org render into a different code and it still doesn't work. Wonder If there's a hint on CoffeScript to eject MyClass from local scope to the outer scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My class is defined inside a closure. Rather what you want to do is "eject" it into the outer scope by setting it to the window object:

```
(function() {

    var myClass = ...

    window.myClass = myClass;

}).call( this );
```

**Update**: It seems you wanted it in CoffeeScript. Here you go:

```
(->

  myClass = (->
    myClass = ->
    myClass::name = (name) ->

    myClass
  )()

  window.myClass = myClass

).call this
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/uyebeb/2/edit)**

Comment: @Martin So you're saying you want the same thing, only in Coffescript?

Comment: Your proposed solution broke somehow when converted to CoffeScript. Wondering if theres a specific method on CoffeScript for this. Otherwise other than nasty at sight It still not work (end up rendering a different code).

Comment: @Martin I'm not familiar with CoffeeScript, I wouldn't know. Though I used the site you referenced and entered the code in. It doesn't seem to do anything wrong. See here -- http://paste.ubuntu.com/1366202/

Answer (score 2):

`MyClass` is defined into the local scope of the self-invoking function. You can try to initialize `MyClass` outside of the self-invoking function:

```
var MyClass;
(function() {

  MyClass = (function() {

    function MyClass() {}

    MyClass.prototype.name = function(name) {};

    return MyClass;

  })();

}).call(this);
```

Another thing you can do is:

```
(function() {
  this.MyClass = (function() {

    function MyClass() {}

    MyClass.prototype.name = function(name) {};

    return MyClass;

  })();

}).call(window);
```

In the code above you're simply invoking the anonymous function with the `window` context and setting value to the `MyClass` window's property (which makes `MyClass` global).

Another solution (which in my opinion is more unclear) is:

```
(function() {

  window.MyClass = (function() {

    function MyClass() {}

    MyClass.prototype.name = function(name) {};

    return MyClass;

  })();

}).call(this);
```

The only difference is that you explicitly say that the property `MyClass` of window will be equals to the result of the execution of the function.

Your CoffeeScript probably could be something like:

```
MyClass = undefined
(->
  MyClass = (->
    MyClass = ->
    MyClass::name = (name) ->

    MyClass
  )()
).call this
```

Comment: I've posted a sample coffeescript