# defining classes for outer scope in CoffeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

This is a follow up to my previous question [Javascript: ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435029/javascript-referenceerror-myclass-is-not-defined).

A .coffee file with this converted to .js will create a `MyClass` available only inside its scope.

```
class MyClass
    name: (name) ->
```

Is there a way in CoffeScript to make the class available to the outer scope? I should be able to `<script src..` the file on a HTML page and instantiate the class from the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll "pollute the global scope" no matter how you do it. It's just a matter of how you do it.

The `@` symbol in CoffeeScript is used to mean "this scope". So you can even use it on a Class definition. The result on a class declaration is that the class is defined in the scope of the `window` object (unless there are some other circumstances, but that's not likely in what you're describing here).

```
class @CustomClassName
    constructor: -> 
        # constructor stuff goes down...
```

---

However, I prefer to do this with a namespace, personally.
Think about `google.maps.Map` or if you've ever written Actionscript 3: `flash.display.MovieClip`.

At the top of your CoffeeScript file put something along the lines of this:

```
window.customnamespace = window.customnamespace || {}
```

Now when you create your class, you can say:

```
class customnamespace.ClassName
    constructor: (container) ->
        # set the container
        @container = container
        # etc...

class customnamespace.OtherClassName
    constructor: ->
        # Another class...
```

In your `document.ready` (if you're using jQuery) you'll globally have access to that namespace and all its classes.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var c = new customnamespace.ClassName($('#container'));

    var other = new customnamespace.OtherClassName();
```

Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

[This stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables) gives a very comprehensive overview of creating global objects with coffeescript with some very good examples included.

For this example the coffeescript:

```
window.MyClass = class MyClass
    name: (name) ->
```

Will compile to:

```
var MyClass;

window.MyClass = MyClass = (function() {

  function MyClass() {}

  MyClass.prototype.name = function(name) {};

  return MyClass;

})();
```

Which will give the same behaviour as the answer to your previous question.